# Are "conversation" and "exchange" interchangeable in some cases?

Tags: meaning

I am learning a [nice ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/210596/109190), which uses a word "**exchange**"

> I think of this as part of an exchange ...

[image]

I was not familiar with this meaning of the word "**exchange**", so I looked it up on Cambridge Dictionary, and got this definition about "**exchange**"

> a short conversation or argument

I guess the part pointed out by red rectangle is a conversation between A and B and is also an exchange.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not interchangeable because **exchange** represents a more general concept than **conversation**.

An [exchange](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exchange) according to the Cambridge Dictionary

> the act of giving something to someone and them giving you something else

A **conversation** is an exchange where you give and receive words (or information).

But if you want groceries and offer money in **exchange**, a simple purchase, that act is not a conversation.

A conversation implies an exchange but an exchange does not always imply a conversation.

Comment: Thank you. In my OP, the part pointed out by red rectangle is a conversation between A and B and is also an exchange.

Comment: @WXJ96163 I agree with you